# Addin FOrm with steps

Tags: php

HI, i want to make a step by step form.

I've made a very basic example in JS. On Each step, i would validate it and then save the stuff into a JS array and save it to DB. Or should i save it into session and use URL parameters? I have a session for sure.

Here the JS example: http://pastebin.com/tApnnqeS

On this example, i have to set it back to 0 since it gets cached. Can i do it in the JS way, or is it somehow stupid?

Comment: What language are you using on the backend?

Comment: It will be a little tool, nothing special. Im using php with sqlite. The whole thing is with url rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at PEAR's [HTML_QuickForm](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm) or [HTML_QuickForm2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2). They support multi-page forms.